# 301 redirect doersnt work in SERP

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, regular-expression

I setup a 301 redirect on my root that points to a new domain. When I type the old domain URL into browser 301 works just fine. When I do a keyword search for my site and click on the link it still takes me to my old site. Below is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?exampleA\.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://exampleB.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I am redirecting from `http://www.exampleA.com` to `http://exampleB.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HTTP_HOST` not `HTTP_REFERER`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank!!! Is there a way to exclude my Wordpress back-end and sitemaps from this? I am still working on a few 301's